# JSON data from iOS to php

Tags: php, ios, json

I want to send json data from iOS to php.my ios code is below:

```
 NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"ishu", @"123", @"hari", @"135", nil];
    NSData *result =[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.4:8888/iostomysql11.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",result.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:result];

     NSData *result1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

and my php code is below:

```
<?php 
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
var_dump($jsonInput);
?>
```

but i got output like this.`bool(false)`.i don't know php that much.what is the wrong in my code?Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$json= file_get_content('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($jsonInput);
```

Make sure you log `result` and `dict` to make sure its fine and  try to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully accomplished the same task:

Following is my code. Hope this helps you

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:m_url];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req addValue:@"getModule" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];

NSMutableDictionary *dicCredentials=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dicCredentials setValue:userid forKey:@"user_id"];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setValue:@"user" forKey:@"moduleName"];
[dictionary setValue:@"getFavourite" forKey:@"methodName"];
[dictionary setValue:dicCredentials forKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"Sent data : %@",dictionary);

//      serialize the dictionary data as json
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[dictionary copy] options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if(error){
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}else{
    [req setHTTPBody:result]; //set the data as the post body

}
[req addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)result.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
if (conn) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data]retain];
}
```

PHP Code :

```
$jsonRequest = file_get_contents('php://input');

$jsonArr = json_decode($jsonRequest, true)
```

Comment: Correct this line in your code. It might help.
NSData *result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[dictionary copy] options:kNilOptions error:&error];

Set options to kNilOptions rather than nil.

Comment: Also check whether data you are sending to the service is in correct format. Otherwise would not be able to decode it on your service end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<?php 
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
?>
```